# React Native on Android: Pressable does not register 'focused' or fires onFocus event

Tags: android, react-native, focus, onfocus, pressable

I admit, I am not a React Native dev, but I have been looking into a project where the devs has a problem getting onFocus triggered when attaching a keyboard to a phone (yes, it sounds strange, but it is for accessibility reasons).

I have experimented with different approaches to getting a trigger when the pressable receives focus, but to no avail. Here are the things I tried.

### Using 'focused' variable

I have tried using the 'focused' variable, but that does not work (doesnt seem to be triggered, but builds and can run). The 'pressed' variable works fine though:

```
return (
  <Pressable
    accessible={true}
    accessibilityRole="button"
    accessibilityLabel={title}
    style={({ pressed, focused }) => [
      styles.container,
      {
        backgroundColor: pressed
          ? theme.colors.buttonPressed
          : (focused
            ? theme.colors.buttonFocused
            : theme.colors.buttonNormal),
      },
      disabled ? styles.disable : styles.able,
    ]}
    disabled={disabled}
    onPress={onPress}

  >
    <View style={[styles.container, style]}>
      {leftIcon && leftIcon}
      <Text numberOfLines={1} style={[styles.buttonText, textStyle]}>
        {title}
      </Text>
      {rightIcon && rightIcon}
    </View>
  </Pressable>
);
```

### Using onFocus events

Here I try to handle it manually:

```
constructor(props) {
 super(props);
 this.state = { isFocused: false };
}

// ....

handleFocus = () => this.setState({ isFocused: true });
handleBlur = () => this.setState({ isFocused: false });

// ...

return (
  <Pressable
    accessible={true}
    accessibilityRole="button"
    accessibilityLabel={title}
    style={({ pressed }) => [
      styles.container,
      {
        backgroundColor: pressed
          ? theme.colors.buttonPressed
          : (this.state.isFocused
            ? theme.colors.buttonFocused
            : theme.colors.buttonNormal), // Updated to buttonNormal
      },
      disabled ? styles.disable : styles.able,
    ]}
    disabled={disabled}
    onPress={onPress}
    onFocus={this.handleFocus} // Handle focus using class method
    onBlur={this.handleBlur} // Handle blur using class method
  >
    <View style={[styles.container, style]}>
      {leftIcon && leftIcon}
      <Text numberOfLines={1} style={[styles.buttonText, textStyle]}>
        {title}
      </Text>
      {rightIcon && rightIcon}
    </View>
  </Pressable>
);
```

I also tried to remove the `style=` from the View, thinking maybe it overrode the Pressable style, but it did not change anything.